# Why is my String initialization throwing a NullPointerError?

Tags: java, android, string, android-studio, nullpointerexception

I've been writing an android application in Android Studio with the purpose of getting a JSONObject from the Google directions API (using the Volley library), then passing it to a new activity (where it will then just be printed, so that I can debug prior to working on parsing it). However upon running the app on my phone through ADB, [LogCat returns this](http://pastebin.com/BWbLc9xN).

The method called by a submit button's onClick (which is when the app crashes) is:

```
public void submit(View view) {
    Location location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(locationClient);
    String destination = findViewById(R.id.destinationInput).toString();
    String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin="
            + location.getLatitude()
            + location.getLongitude()
            + "&destination=" + destination
            + "&mode=driving"
            + avoids()
            + "departure_time=now"
            + "&key=" + getString(R.string.API_KEY);

    RequestQueue requestQueue;
    // Instantiate the cache
    Cache cache = new DiskBasedCache(getCacheDir(), 1024 * 1024); // 1MB cap
    // Set up the network to use HttpURLConnection as the HTTP client.
    Network network = new BasicNetwork(new HurlStack());
    // Instantiate the RequestQueue with the cache and network.
    requestQueue = new RequestQueue(cache, network);
    // Start the queue
    requestQueue.start();

    JsonObjectRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
            (Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject dirs) {
                    Intent intent;
                    intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DisplayDirections.class);
                    intent.putExtra("DIRECTIONS", dirs.toString());
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                }
            });
    // Add the request to the RequestQueue.
    requestQueue.add(jsObjRequest);
}

private String avoids() {
    String avoid = "avoid=";
    boolean any = false;
    if(((Switch) findViewById(R.id.avoidTollsSwitch)).isChecked()) {
        avoid += "tolls";
        any = true;
    }
    if(((Switch) findViewById(R.id.avoidMotorwaysSwitch)).isChecked()) {
        if(any) avoid += "|";
        avoid += "highways";
        any = true;
    }
    if(((Switch) findViewById(R.id.avoidFerriesSwitch)).isChecked()) {
        if(any) avoid += "|";
        avoid += "ferries";
        any = true;
    }
    if(any) return avoid;
    else return "";
}
```

The LogCat log links to the line String url =, but I'm confused as to what's wrong with this line. As far as I can tell, my code should work...

Volley tutorial: https://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple.html

Comment: maybe location is null?

Comment: please,provide the full stack trace

Comment: `LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(...)` can return `null` under certain circumstances. Check before you act.

Comment: Shouldn't `avoid=` be `&avoid=`? Also an `&` before departure?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that `location` is not null? Put a breakpoint on the `String url =` line and see what its value is.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running it on the emulator you need to have sent coordinates to the emulator. Otherwise `location` will be null.

I was pulling my hair over it the first time I used geolocation services.

Just do a check like

```
if (location!=null) {
foo.doSomethingWithLocation(bar);
} else {
 Log.d(TAG, "Sorry. Location is null");
}
```

before you call anything